# how to query once and display multiple times with where clause?

Tags: php, pdo

I want to learn how to query once and display in multiple boxes with
 where clause?

like :

if status 1 ? : display in `<div class="1">` elseif status 2 ?: `<div class="2">` etc. etc.

I know my answer is in my question and I need to do if statements, but I dont know how to display while loop or foreach a few times with same query.

Here is my query :

```
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

    }
```

I have searched on google got a few examples like this with for loop but I didnt find any examples with where claus.

```
$i;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

}
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
}
```

I tried if statment without foreach loop :

```
if($status == 1){
  foreach(){
    echo "Display box 1";
  }
}

if($status == 2){
  foreach(){
    echo "Display box 2";
  }
}
```

Displaying only one post need while loop or foreach to display all posts with status 1
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could buffer multiple streams, read the entire dataset into a PHP array and search it or run multiple queries, all are unnecessary and inefficient. Just sort the query. Consider:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY status");
$stmt->execute();
$prevstatus=-1;
print "<div style='display:none'>";
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
   if ($row['status']!=$prevstatus) {
      $prevstatus=$row['status'];
      print "</div><div class='$prevstatus'>";
   }
   print ....
}
print "</div>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! runing multiple queries in same page was slowing page load, that is why I wanted to know if there is a way to run one `query` instead of multiple. if unnecessary I will run  multi queries than.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question but:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles");
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo "<div class=\"class_". $row["status"] ."\">div content</div>\n";
}
```

And - CSS classes can not begin with numbers or have only numbers as a name! In my example I use .class_x (where X is your value from database)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tomas! I just corected query to should be. my question is simple. how can I display multiple while loop or foreach in same page but diferent boxes with one query. instead of querying each time ?

Comment: I modified code example - now your query return all from table articles. In loop script write DIVs with class joined with status column. if you set: .class_1 { color: red; } .class_2 { color: blue; } .... you will see result